# Excel - Bulk deletion of same words and rest of differing brackets content

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, bulk, office-2010

I am compiling a glossary in excel, with entries coming from different sources. In the attempt to make it more uniform, I intend to delete the content of the "definition" rows indicating the field of usage of certain definitions.

My aim is to delete at once

```
(wordA wordB) 
(wordA wordC) 
(wordA wordD wordE)
```

from

```
(wordA wordB) text1
(wordA wordC) text2
(wordA wordD wordE) text3
```

in all rows, deleting also the space after the bracket but leaving

```
text1
text2
text3
```

untouched. Thank you in advance for any contribution.
PS: my office version is 2010, but can get access to a PC with the latest version if required!

**ADDITION**
Thank you very much for your contributions, but I forgot to add that some definitions have brackets containing useful information

```
(wordA wordB) text1
(wordA wordC) text2
(wordA wordD wordE) text3
(wordA wordF) text4 (useful info between brackets) text
```

Hence I need to be able to retain everything contained in the cell, except for the content of brackets containing "wordA"

Comment: Are the definition in individual cells?

Comment: do a find/replace ie find (*) and replace with ""

Comment: @Whizhi Yes, they are in individual cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data looks like this:

[image]

You can use:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(") ",A1))
```

to remove all the words before "`)` "

---

I just have to share @Solar Mikes solution in the comment because it's *amazing!!*:

In "Find and Replace" you enter in the field Find what: "`(*)`" (with a space after the last bracket)

Because it will find anything in the bracket [* = wildcard] and replace that.

And replace with "nothing" aka "".

[image]

Output will be this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I forgot to mention a few things. Let me update my post!

Comment: Done. Your solution would indeed be viable and very valid. Unfortunately here I need to spare some bracketed content, and that would be too drastic

Comment: Yes, that is just perfect. Cannot test it on a newer Excel right now (Excel 2010 won't recognize the function - signalling an error), but that is exactly what I needed. Being a newbie in Excel, could you kindly explain to me what parameter sets it in a way that the first ")" is used and not the second one? (I would have expected "text4" to be deleted as well)

Comment: Then use find replace with the terms you do want to delete, not explaining clearly makes it hard for us to help.

Comment: The `FIND` value is going to stop at the first bracket. In your case that's what you want. So.. `LEN` shows us how many characters there are in the cell, and `FIND` function will find the position of the FIRST bracket from left to return. `(LEN(A1)` - `FIND())`, will be how many characters from the right the `RIGHT` function should return. [Examples and details can be found here](https://www.excelfunctions.net/split-string-in-excel.html) :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Wizhi!

Comment: My apologies Solar Mike, I appreciate your intention to help me, and hope you'll accept my apologies for my lack of clarity. Didn't mean to make you waste time and effort, and least of all upset you. Thanks for your help as well!

Comment: @ed0, Np, for me ;). I like to help people :D, The more complete the data set is, the easier it's to help/take into account what problems that might occur :). Take care, wish you the best and feel free to ask if there are anything!!

Comment: @Wizhi, as you rightfully said, the more complete the data set, the easier to foresee the issues! If you have time to give a look at it, I have extracted an even more significative sample, boldened what I am aiming at removing, and highlighted other cases (all of them this time) which would still get negatively affected, if you can help sort things out . Thank you once more! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-JXBZpuTezv54vgmxnM4sHl2gp54mkO5YOr5TsTMu8/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @wizhi, Sorry to bother you, can I recall your attention on my comment above? Thanks :)

Comment: I took a look but I don't really follow what you want to achieve. How do I know that some brackets should be removed, while other deleted? I would strongly suggest to create a new question with the detailed data. Please highlight why some **brackets should be removed, while other should not** :). I think the logic is more advanced and I'm sure that other people know the solution better than me :)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Text to Column" function of excel. Your data will be segregated exactly the way you need in different columns then just delete the column you don't need.

Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: That's well thought of, but I think that since I have different amounts of words in different brackets, some of the in-brackets content would end up in the same column as out-of-brackets text from cells below. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Yes It might happen. My answer was based on the pattern you shared. You can check this once by copying your data in a different sheet. If it works, we will have one more way of solving the problem. I am new to excel so just exploring things..